# opening file upload window using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a button or link button. I want to open a window for file uploading by clicking the button or link button. Actually at that time I won't have any file upload control there.
can any one tell me how to do it by using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'window for file uploading'?  (????????)  Do you mean the OS file browser dialog?  Or are you just talking about another HTML page with a form on it?

Comment: Window for file uploading means OS file browser dialog.Actually I want to upload files like Gmail style..........

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="window.open('the_page_containing_the_upload_form.html', 'Upload form')">Upload</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking that you want to open up the file upload dialog with a click of something other than the input element itself.

You can not just open up the file upload dialog since that is sort of a thing we call a security issue. [You can style the input field to make it look like something else](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Comment: Window for file uploading means OS file browser dialog.Actually I want to upload files like Gmail style..........